# Apache won't load php_curl.dll

Tags: php, apache, curl

Apache is giving me this error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:/Users/tester/Desktop/Web Server/php-7.2.5-Win32-VC15-x64/ext/curl (The specified module could not be found.), C:/Users/tester/Desktop/Web Server/php-7.2.5-Win32-VC15-x64/ext/php_curl.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

This is a 64bit Windows server 2016 install.

This PHP https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.2.5-Win32-VC15-x64.zip

This Apache: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC15/binaries/httpd-2.4.33-win64-VC15.zip

All the other modules work+load fine.

I've tried adding the ext path to my system variables.

I've tried using a 32bit version of PHP_curl.dll

I've tried copying libeay32.dll, libssh2.dll, ssleay32.dll into pretty much everywhere. Apache root, ext folder.

What else can I try here?

Comment: Quoth the PHP manual on curl, installing, and win32 - "Note: Note to Win32 Users
In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, or, as of OpenSSL 1.1 libcrypto-\*.dll and libssl-\*.dll, must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site."

Comment: They all are :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the end I had to simply copy libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssh2.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll and nghttp2.dll from the PHP folder into the apache bin folder.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Tried all sorts of suggestions. Thanks mate.

Comment: Tnx. The same issue happened to me after updating the PHP from v7.1 to v7.2.

Comment: Apache\bin had all but libssh2.dll. Once I added it, everything worked

Answer (score 6):

### In PHP 7.4:

Most probably it's a problem related only to `Windows`, if you are using `Apache2.4` + `Php7`, the trick consists in using `LoadFile` directive to force the loading of `CURL` as explained in my [Mini Guide](https://gist.github.com/alecos71/de26b0079b963a690e798375b8561dfa). You don't need strange things to have `CURL` working on your machine, you need to edit the file `httpd.conf` and add this:

```
LoadFile "${MY_PHP_ROOT}/libssh2.dll"
```

So full PHP incantation in `httpd.conf` might look something like this:

```ini
##
#BEGIN PHP
Define MY_PHP_ROOT "c:/Dev/PHPs/PHP74"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "${MY_PHP_ROOT}/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "${MY_PHP_ROOT}/"

# Load library required for CURL
LoadFile "${MY_PHP_ROOT}/libssh2.dll"

#END PHP
##
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Order of LoadModule/LoadFile doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me on Win10 with Apache2.4 and PHP7

Comment: This solution is by far cleaner than the accepted one and avoids making copies of the dll which will certainly diverge over the time.

Comment: Note that this works because other libraries are already provided with Apache 2.4. So you probably already have `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`, `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` and `nghttp2.dll` in Apache bin folder.

Comment: In PHP 8.1 it works this way:
LoadFile "C:/Apache24/php-8.1.21-Win32-vs16-x64/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"
LoadFile "C:/Apache24/php-8.1.21-Win32-vs16-x64/libssl-1_1-x64.dll"
LoadFile "C:/Apache24/php-8.1.21-Win32-vs16-x64/libssh2.dll"
nghttp2.dll is also required, but already present in Apache24\bin.